# Inject parser implementation depends on condition

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am looking for a best solution to organize code in the project. So, I have a big position string that comes from external service. That looks something like that:

```
"2020-01-03     some    values  13DHELLO   andmore  values"
```

Also with this string that need to parse I have different properties. Depends on the property I need to inject the specific parser implementation and pass there a string to map specific model. Every parser implementation ***returns different model***.
Right now I have implemented some logic like:

```
switch (response.getParameter()) {
        case FIRST_PARAMETER:
            switch (response.getAdditionalInfo()) {
                case NESTED_FIRST_PARAMETER:
                    return new FirstParser(response.getData()).parse();
                case NESTED_SECOND_PARAMETER:
                    return new SecondParser(response.getData()).parse();
                case NESTED_THIRD_PARAMETER:
                    return new ThirdParser(response.getData()).parse();
                default:
                    break;
            }
        case SECOND_PARAMETER:
            return new SecondParameterParser(response.getData()).parse();
        default:
            break;
}
```

That looks very scary and difficult to extend. I'm thinking about the way or patterns to make this better. Maybe get a HashMap and receive bean implementation of parser depends on enum value. Nevertheless I don't what to do with nested cases.
Hope you can help me to find pattern to solve this task and make code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, providing some kind or repository (a simple one could be a map) would be a good start. That way you could return a parser factory, e.g. a `FirstParserFactory` that creates a new `FirstParser` from the response.

Simplified example with a lot of checks and other code missing (I'll leave that to you :) ):

Factory

```
interface ParserFactory {
  Parser createParser(Response resp);
}

class FirstParserFactory implements ParserFactory  {
  public Parser createParser(Response resp) {
    return new FirstParser(resp.getData());
  }
}
```

Usage

```
Map<String, ParserFactory> repository = ... //build

respository.get(response.getParameter()).createParser(response).parse();
```

Nested cases could be handled by a nestable factory, e.g. like this:

```
class NestedParserFactory implements ParserFactory {
  Map<String, ParserFactory> nestedFactories = ...;

  public Parser createParser(Response resp) {
    ParserFactory nestedFactory = nestedFactories.get(resp.getAdditionalInfo());
    if( nestedFactory == null ) {
      return null; //or handle in any other appropriate way
    }

    return nestedFactory.createParser(response);
  }  
}
```